# Is it possible to reuse a binary_oarchive instance?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, boost-serialization

My question is the same as discussed in [this thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/serialization-Archive-reuse-td2604405.html) from five years ago (which has no good answer).

I'm serializing my objects into a byte buffer, like so:

```
std::string serial_str;
for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
{
    boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string> inserter(serial_str);
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string> > s(inserter);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(s);

    oa << obj;

    s.flush();

    // code to send serial_str's content to another process, omitted.

    serial_str.clear(); // clear the buffer so it can be reused to serialize the next object
}
```

When I do this in a loop, the performance is quite bad: I get ~14,000 objects / sec.

I've pinpointed the problem down to the recreation of the binary_oarchive. If I just write into the same string with the same archive instance in a loop, I get ~220,000 objects/sec, but then, the objects are serialized one after the other sequentially, which isn't what I want: I want to clear and reuse the same buffer (seek to its beginning) after each object is serialized.

How can I do that?

Comment: Then what's the point of having the buffer at all, if you're going to throw away its contents as soon as they're written?

Comment: What is exactly included in the loop? If you declare `serial_str` also you don't have to clear it, because it is created in each loop.

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, I should've mentioned that after serializing each object, I'm sending its content to another process using boost::interprocess::message_queue.

Comment: @Omer: Aha! Yes, you should have. :)

Comment: @Diego @Tomalak My apologies, I've updated my code to fix these problems.

Comment: See this post for another relevant answer http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Serialization-Speedding-up-client-server-communication-td2584358.html#a2584359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can reuse it, in a sense. The oarchive simply wraps up a stream and doesn't know what's going on with the stream's data, so the trick is to implement your own stream (which isn't fun) to allow you to "reset" the actual underlaying data stream. I've written something like this before and it works wonderfully.

Some gotchas to be aware of though:

The oarchive won't keep writing out header information (since if it persists it's treating everything as one big stream), so you'll want to disable the headers:

```
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(s, boost::archive::no_codecvt | boost::archive::no_header);
```

Also, because you're reusing an oarchive, you have to be extremely careful about managing its internal type table. If all you're serializing are ints, floats, etc, then you'll be fine, but as soon as you start serializing classes, strings, and the like you can't rely on the default type enumeration that the archive uses when reusing the archive like this. The Boost documentation doesn't really get into this, but for anything complex, you need to do the following for *every* type the archive will come across:

```
oa.template register_type<std::string>();
oa.template register_type<MyClass>();
oa.template register_type<std::shared_ptr<MyClass> >();
```

And so on.. for all your types, all std::vectors of them, all std::shared_ptrs of them, etc. This is *vital*. Otherwise you'll only be able to read back your streams if you use a shared iarchive and read them in the exact same order they were serialized out.

The consequence is that your iarchive needs to register all the types in the exact same way and order as their oarchive (I wrote some handy helpers using mpl to do help me with this).

Serializing back in through an iarchive can also share the same iarchive, however all the same conditions apply:

- You need to write your own stream (so it can be redirected/reset)
- Disable the archive headers
- Have the register types

So yes, reusing an oarchive/iarchive is possible, but it's a bit of a pain. Once you've got it sorted out though, it's pretty awesome.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! Could you expand a bit on why I have to write my own stream, and can't just reuse one from the boost library, and how I could go about building it? How would my custom stream be different than say, a std::stringstream?

Comment: You need to use your own stream if you want to point it to different targets. For me, I was thinking of files, but it still applies to your code. You need a new stream for each new string, and so if you don't write your own stream this means you need a new oarchive for each new string. Looking at your code, it suggests you're reusing the string by clearing it, so this will suffice. If you had to switch to a different string, then you'd need a custom stream to allow this. However, what I said about headers and type registration still applies.

Comment: If your deserialization and serialization are kept in perfect sync (so no persistent storage) just straight out->in, you might even be able to avoid changing the headers and dealing with type registration. However, this is risky and very fragile. (assuming you have an iarchive on the other side that's reading in your strings)

Comment: That is fun with Boost.Iostreams

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I came up with.
It does not require implementation of your own stream and allows to reuse the same chunk of memory for each next serialization. 
Supposed that you have following structures arranged for serialization:

```
boost::iostreams::basic_array<char> sink; // target buffer 
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::basic_array<char> > os;  // stream wrapper around it
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa;  // archive which uses this stream
```

Then to reuse the same buffer just reopen the stream:

```
os.close();
os.open(sink);
```

Should be as fast as changing some internal pointers inside the stream. I have not tested the actual speed, although.

Code for trying this out:
Writer serializes passed pointer to the buffer.
Reader deserializes pointer from the same buffer (same buffer is shared between reader and writer)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

class A;
class Writer {
    char *buf;
    int len;
    boost::iostreams::basic_array<char> sink;
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::basic_array<char> > os;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa;
public:
    Writer(char *_buf, int _len): buf(_buf), len(_len), sink(buf, len), os(sink), oa(os) {}
    void write(A* a) {
        oa << a;
    }
    void reset() {
        os.close();
        os.open(sink);
    }
};
class Reader {
    char *buf;
    int len;
    boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> src;
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> > is;
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia;
public:
    Reader(char *_buf, int _len): buf(_buf), len(_len), src(buf, len), is(src), ia(is) {}
    A* read() {
        A* a;
        ia >> a;
        return a;
    }
    void reset() {
        is.close();
        is.open(src);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // to memory
    char buffer[4096] = {0};

    Writer w(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    A *a1 = new A(5);
    w.write(a1);

    Reader r(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    A *a2 (NULL);
    a2 = r.read();

    assert(*a1 == *a2);
    std::cout << "Simple ok\n";

    // test reuse
    w.reset();
    r.reset();

    A *a3 (NULL);
    w.write(new A(10));
    a3 = r.read();

    assert(*a3 == A(10));
    std::cout << "Reuse ok\n";
};

class A
{
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  int i;

  template <typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
    std::cout << "serialize A\n";
    ar & i;
  }
public:
  A(): i(0) {};
  A(int _i): i(_i) {};
  virtual bool operator==(const A&r) { return i == r.i; };

  virtual ~A() {};
  virtual void whoa() {std::cout << "I am A!\n";};
  virtual const char* me() { return "A"; };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution, without having to look much further would be to store the last length of the string, and get the substring using the last length and actual length (will be the last string added to the output). Each 10 or 100 iterations you can restart the `binary_oarchive` not to accumulate much past encoded objects in `serial_str`.

Comment: Thanks, I considered that, but seems like there ought to be an out-of-the-box solution somehow?

Comment: OK, the problem here is that `back_insert_device` is not seekable, so you can't seek it to the beginning.

Comment: oh, ic! I think boost::iostreams::basic_array IS seekable, I'll try to use that instead and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest that, but I don't have experience with boost streams. Also, note that creating the `binary_oarchive` is not that costly, because it just uses the streambuf from the given stream (stores a reference to it), so just winding the stream and creating a new `binary_oarchive` will maintain performance.